# Determine derivative time of real PID controller

Tags: pid-controller, time, calculation

I need help determining the derivative time of a real PID controller.

[image: PID controller]

Above me is an ideal PID controller. In my case I have another resistor (let us say R0) before R1 and Cd serial.

How do I now get the derivative time? How do I calculate it?

This is the tf I currently have: \begin{equation}
G(s)=\frac{R_2}{C_iR_2(R_0+R_1)}\cdot\frac{(1+sC_iR_2)(1+sC_1R_1)}{(1+s\frac{C_1R_0R_1}{R_0+R_1})}
 \end{equation}

Comment: Is this homework?  It's more complicated than that -- you'll be modifying \$Kp\$, and I think \$Ki\$ as well (but I'd have to work through it to be sure about \$Ki\$).  If this _is_ homework, then _edit your question_ to show the work you've done so far.

Comment: In your op-amp compensator, there is a pole at the origin, meaning the gain must be infinite - the open-loop gain of the op-amp - when \$s=0\$. I don't see this happening in your equation. Then I would recommend you translate your PID time-domain equation in the Laplace domain and rearrange the terms to match those you'll get with your filter. Look at my [APEC seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf) for the filtered PID correspondence with a type 3 compensator as an example.

Answer (score 0):

derivative time belongs discrete-time domain. But this equation is in the continuous-time domain. We don't have sampling time or derivative time in the continuous-time domain.
If you discretize this equation you can define derivative time for the controller.